# Django group objects by foreign key and count

Tags: python, django, orm, group-by

I have stored a Url table in my database with the following structure:

*[Entry 1]*

```
Url: ForeignKey(Url)
Referer Url: http://facebook.com/post/123
User Agent: Mozilla etc...
IP: 123.123.123.123
Is under proxy?: True
```

All the entries are similar to the one above.

I need to group all the entries by the **Url** column and then count how many entries with the same **Url** column have the same User Agent, IP and Referer Url.

Is there any way to do it with Django ORM?

---

**Example**:

Entries with same **Url** column: 12 of these have XXX referal, 6 of thees have YYY referal, 10 of these have XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX IP, 100 of thees have YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY IP

---

Can anyone explain me the logic to use behind this process?

---

**UPDATE** Ok guys, I did it on my own. Here is the code:

```
urls = Url.objects.all() # select all urls
    for url in urls: # for each url count how many times the same ip, useragent, etc... are repeated
        visits = VisitLog.objects.filter(url=url)
        visit_ip = visits.values('ip').annotate(ip_count=Count('ip'))
        visit_useragent = visits.values('useragent').annotate(useragent_count=Count('useragent'))
        visit_referring_url = visits.values('referring_url').annotate(referring_url_count=Count('referring_url'))
        print(visit_referring_url)
```

Now is there a way to do it in a more elegant way without so many queries?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use the ORM for this. You'll likely have to pull out all the unique combinations of User Agent, IP and Referrer URLs. Then go and fetch the count of entries that match each one.

You may end up using `raw` or writing [custom SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

The first thing that comes to mind is to run a select against the instances table looking for a distinct values across all four of your columns. Those results will then need to be used to count the duplicates.